# how to solve the certification issues in puppet

Tags: docker, certificate, ubuntu-14.04, puppet

I have installed docker in my ubuntu 14.04 OS.In docker containers im running puppet master and puppet agent.But im getting errors during the certificate exchange.
The puppet agent is not requesting certificates.Also showing an error saying the name cannot be resolved.
I checked the IP and hostname in /etc/hosts and /etc/hostname.

```
root@55fe460464d3:/# puppet agent --test
Error: Could not request certificate: getaddrinfo: Name or service not known
Exiting; failed to retrieve certificate and waitforcert is disabled

root@f7d7516d720e:/# puppet cert list -all
+ "f7d7516d720e" (SHA256) D1:6C:50:5B:BD:F6:AA:91:C4:B2:FD:4D:58:B8:DF:18:32:F4:EB:D7:B2:75:FF:E4:AF:7B:F6:F6:FE:0D:84:54
```

The puppet cert list --all command is showing only the master certificate,not the client certificate

Answer (score 0):

What it looks like is happening is that the puppet agent can't talk to or find the puppetmaster to ask for a certificate.

The first thing to check would be that they can talk to each other over the network; the second thing to check is that the short hostname `puppet` resolves to the puppetmaster when run on the host. Unless you've specified a different dns name in /etc/puppet/puppet.conf by setting a `server =`directive in the `[main]` section or specified it on the command line with `puppet agent -t --server <foo>`, it will look for a hostname called `puppet` and rely on your `/etc/resolv.conf`'s search domains to find it.

Comment: root@55fe460464d3:/# puppet agent -t --server pmaster.example.com
Info: Creating a new SSL key for 55fe460464d3
Error: Could not request certificate: Connection refused - connect(2)
Exiting; failed to retrieve certificate and waitforcert is disabled

Comment: Are the two machines able to talk to each other over the network on puppet's port (8140)? Because connect(2) fails for [several reasons](http://linux.die.net/man/2/connect), but it's almost guaranteed to be a reachability issue.

Comment: The problem was with the host-name because the host-name remained the same i.e. container ID ,even we edit in etc/hosts and /etc/host-name.I corrected it by setting the host-name using docker run -h host-name.           Example : sudo docker run -it -h test.example.com ubuntu /bin/bash. Its working perfectly.